# Updating a nested record, rails will send to SQL to update the parent record id to "nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have a problem in updating a nested record from its parent record update page (creation works fine).

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

...

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_visites_path @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

...

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

...

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:some_attributes, profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :birthdate, :first_interview, :send_by, :sexe, :tall, :weight, :etc_attributes])
end

# app/model/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# app/model/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :last_interview

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  has_many :visites
end
```

When I do send the update request with the params:

```
{"some_attributes"=>"",
 "profile_attributes"=>
  {"first_name"=>"Jean",
   "last_name"=>"Paul",
   "birthdate(3i)"=>"14",
   "birthdate(2i)"=>"11",
   "birthdate(1i)"=>"2017",
   "first_interview(3i)"=>"12",
   "first_interview(2i)"=>"11",
   "first_interview(1i)"=>"2017",
   "send_by"=>"",
   "tall"=>"",
   "weight"=>"",
   "etc_attributes"=>""}}
```

I am getting the following error from the logs:

```
Profile Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 414]]
SQL (2.7ms)  UPDATE "profiles" SET "user_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "profiles"."id" = ?  [["user_id", nil], ["updated_at", "2017-11-28 00:36:37.936914"], ["id", 4]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: profiles.user_id: UPDATE "profiles" SET "user_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "profiles"."id" = ?
```

The weird part is that at the second request rails does to SQL it tries to reset "user_id" and more problematic to `nil` which is causing me the error.

Do you have an idea why and also, how to avoid it?

Comment: You have to pass `user_id` in params

Comment: But isn't it weird or a bad practice to set an attributes to the exact same value as it is already?